# #VALUE! Error while trying to use a referencing cell in a formula

Tags: openoffice, spreadsheet

I would like to use the value inside a cell which continuously gets updated from a web page. The cell called C20 linked to another sheet called `ratedatasheet` and that sheet displays a page and table from a site online.

I want to use the value inside C20 (linked as `RATEDATASHEET.A79`) in a formula such as this one:

```
=IF(E24=0;A24*C20;A24*C24)
```

This formula is placed in B24 cell and, all I am getting as a result is `#VALUE!` error. I tried like removing the letters from the source cell but it did not help.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I have tried both formulas mentioned below:

```
IF(E24=0;A24*(value(C20));A24*C24)
```

and

```
IF(E24=0;A24*(indirect(C20));A24*C24)
```

in return I face with the `ERR502` and as I see from the manual, it means 'A function argument has an invalid value, e.g. a negative number for the root function.'

C20 cell contains value such as '2,820250 TL' which is continuously being updated by the other sheet called 'ratedatasheet'. Formula is placed inside cell B24 where I want to see the result.

[image: PrtSC of the table]

**UPDATE 2**

Okay, the new formula I have tried is
`IF(E24=0;A24*VALUE(LEFT(C20;FIND(",";C20)-1));A24*C24)`
This helped to extract the "2" from the value inside C20 (2,826250 TL) I also need to work on implementing the rest of the value (.826250 TL) Your suggestions on this are welcome!

**FINAL UPDATE**

Can anybody explain me the interpretation of this formula which worked out for me please ?!

```
IF(E24=0;A24*VALUE(LEFT(C20;FIND(" ";C20;1)-4))/1000;A24*C24)
```

Comment: You need Indirect(C21) to use the value inside C21

Comment: Hi @SuperSam How to define the C20 (I mistyped it sorry) as indirect? If I do so, will I still get an updated result of the formula as I want? Thanks

Comment: maybe you can just write value(C20) instead of just C20

Comment: The update will not be affected but I think c20 is treated as text

Comment: @SuperSam I've already tried as IF(E24=0;A24*(C20);A24*C24) nothing has changed. Yes I think the same about recognizing the C20 as text.

Comment: IF(E24=0;A24*(value(C20));A24*C24) try this and write for me what exactly c20 shows

Comment: With indirect try like this =IF(E24=0;A24*(indirect(C20));A24*C24)

Comment: @SuperSam I posted the result above. Unfortunatelly te suggestions haven't hepled so far. Would the 'comma' inside the cell C20 cause this? I cannot delete it since the data comes with comma from the web page.

Comment: =IF(E24=0;A24*(indirect("C20"));A24*C24) use C20 between quotes if you have comma, what exactly is written in C20

Comment: @SuperSam No use. Now it gives #NAME! error (

Comment: You asked for an interpretation of `IF(E24=0;A24*VALUE(LEFT(C20;FIND(" ";C20;1)-4))/1000;A24*C24)`. I'll start from the middle: `FIND(" ";C20;1)` means "In C20, starting from the 1st character, in what position is the first space character?" `LEFT(C20;FIND(...)-4)` means "Give me the leftmost *n* characters in C20, where *n* is 4 less than the first space position." `VALUE(LEFT(...))` means "Convert that text to a number." `IF(E24=0;A24*VALUE(...)/1000;A24*C24)` means "If E24 is zero, then multiply A24 by that value extracted from C20, then divide by 1000. Otherwise, multiply A24 by C24."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the additional information from your edits, it is apparent that your problem is twofold:

- The contents of C20 are formatted as text and need to be converted to number formatting before using in a calculation
- The contents of C20 contain text characters that need to be stripped before the conversion to a number can be successful

If the contents will always be in the format "number text" then you can search for the space and strip off the space and the text characters that follow it before converting to a number.  Something like

```
=IF(E24=0;A24*VALUE(LEFT(C20;FIND(" ";C20)-1));A24*C24)
```

**Edit**

From the UPDATE2 it seems the text cell includes a number with a `,` as the decimal mark while the OP's locale uses a `.` as a decimal mark and a `,` as a thousands separator.  The OP found that if they limited the number of post-decimal mark digits to 3 that the `VALUE` function would interpret the `,` as a thousand separator, and the number could be divided by 1,000 to move the decimal mark to the correct location.

A solution that would avoid cutting off the last three decimal places would be to use `SUBSTITUTE` to replace the `,` with a `.` before running the `VALUE` function:

```
=IF(E24=0;A24*VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(C20;FIND(" ";C20)-1);",";"."));A24*C24)
```

Comment: Hello Lyrl,
I have tried your suggestion right away without making any changes to the formula you wrote. I got the same VALUE! error. Then I put comma between quotes (",";C20) and it gave me result. I was happy till I realized that it only used the number that comes before the comma (C20 currently show the number 2,826250 TL which is 2.826250 TL and your formula with my comma in it uses only the number "2" to calculate) Well I think we are close to the solution. So the next question is how to implement the rest of the value (.826250 TL) Thanks

Comment: Okay, I did it but I don't know how. I just was playing around with the number of formula that you have provided. Here is the formula that worked for me. It works with little bit deviation.
=IF(E24=0;A24*VALUE(LEFT(C20;FIND(" ";C20;1)-4))/1000;A24*C24)
I had to devide the extracted value with '1000' to put the "," or "." in place.

Answer (score 1):

IN CONCLUSION,

After studying how the functions work, I have come up with the formula below which is shorter and gives the exact result that is needed. I hope it helps someone.

```
=IF(E24=0;A24*VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(C20;8);",";"."));A24*C24)
```

- No use of 'FIND' function or dividing with 1000 is needed.
- Number '8' in the formula means 'from left to the right include all of 8 characters (ie 2,826250). So we avoid the 'space' and etc. this way since it is located in string 9.
- SUBSTITUTE formula changes ',' with '.' to make calculation possible since the computer uses '.' for calculation. Despite of this substitution, result of the formula contains the "," as decimal separator. So, we get what we want anyway. (Comma is used as a decimal separator in my country)

Using this method you can use external online data inside your formulas to do calculation. 
`VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(C20;8);",";"."))` - this is the part of the above mentioned formula that turns raw data into value that can be used for calculations

UPDATE: Cell C20 contains the raw data (2,826250 TL) that is derived from a webpage using Calc's "Link to External Data" feature.

Thanks to the contributors

Comment: I'm confused by the `E$21` in this answer. Column E isn't shown in your screenshot nor discussed in the question, so without knowing what E21 contains, this formula isn't very helpful.

Comment: @DanHenderson I have added an update above according to your question. By the way, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: So it's the same as C20?

Comment: @DanHenderson Exactly!

Comment: In that case, it might be much clearer, and simpler, to just use C20 in your answer, to remain consistent with the information provided in the question.